# Check Values Method Not Working for Checking for a Magic Square

Tags: java

This method is always returning false even when the correct numbers are inputted. If the numbers 1-n^2 and no duplicates are entered then it should return true.

```
   public boolean checkValues()
{
  int numCounter=1;
  boolean okay=false;
  while (numCounter<=n*n)
  {
     for (int i=0; i< n ; i++) 
     {
        for (int j=0; j< n ; j++)
        {
           if ((int) square.get(i).get(j)==numCounter)
              okay=true;  
        }
     }
     okay=false;
     numCounter++;
  }
  if (numCounter==n*n)
     return true;
  else 
     return false;  
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more what are the values expected by this method. You shouldn't expect everyone know 'magi square'. It's difficult to find out what you are trying to implement specially when the code is not working correctly.

Comment: Sorry! What I'm doing is inputting numbers into an arraylist of arraylist and checking if the numbers 1-n^2 (n^2 is the size of the larger arraylist) are there and that there are no duplicates. There is more to a magic square but I have those methods working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if (numCounter==n*n)` to `if (numCounter==n*n+1)` since your while-loop finally would do a `numCounter++;` again, or replace `while (numCounter<=n*n)` with `while(numCounter<n*n)` if `n*n` is not really required to be checked

Updated:

I noticed that you don't really use `okay` in the end, I think you might need to change to:

```
public boolean checkValues()
{
  int numCounter=1;
  boolean okay=false;
  while (numCounter<=n*n)
  {
     ok = false;
     for (int i=0; i< n ; i++) 
     {
        for (int j=0; j< n ; j++)
        {
           if ((int) square.get(i).get(j)==numCounter)
              ok=true;  
        }
     }
     if(!ok)  // numCounter cannot be found
         return false;
     numCounter++;
  }
  return true; // successfully passed the check through 1 to n^2 
}
```

However, I think a better solution in terms of time complexity is as follows, which you can use a `HashSet` to check duplicates for you.

```
public boolean checkValues()
{
     Set<Integer> total = new HashSet<Integer>();
     for (int i=0; i< n ; i++){
        for (int j=0; j< n ; j++){
           int num = square.get(i).get(j);
           if(num>=1 && num<=n*n)
               total.add(num);
        }
     }
     if(total.size() == n*n)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: The only issue is that adding okay back in got it stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @newAtJava I just added numCounter++ in the end of while-loop, that is required